# Troubles calling web services with WSDL Importer

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-2010

I have built an application that calls a webservice in order to retrieve some information. This application is designed to work both on android and windows (using the firemonkey framework).
The object that calls the webservice has been built with a WSDL importer and works great when running the application on windows.

Nonetheless, when i try to use my application on an android device, i can only call the webservice two times. On the third time, the application freeze.

I have tried to do some debug and it appears that the application freezes when trying to call the web service :

```
genEtq := GetIGenerationEtiquettes(); // Converts a THttpRio as a IGenerationEtiquette object
soapattachmnt := genEtq.GetImageEtiquette(idEtiquette); // Calls web service -> freeze on third time
//
// Do something ...
//
```

The webservice is hosted on my computer so i'm sure there is no troubles on the service side. In addition, when i restart the application, i can still call the web service two times.

My application has the authorization to access to the internet on my android device so i'm running out of ideas on what's the problem.
Also i have tried to monitor the network (via wireshark) and i had been able to see the two first requests but not the third one.

Do you have any ideas on how to find the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found the answer, my mistake was to call everytime the GetIGenerationEtiquettes() function instead of storing the resulting object.

Now i can call my webservice as often as i want.

Hope this answer will help someone.